# trap int3 error in libglib - debian eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, debian

I get this error randomly while using eclipse IDE with my PC turned on for more than a day:

(kern.log)

```
trap: java [16410] trap int3 ip: 7f2a62422c75 sp: 7f2a9f686da0 error: 0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.5800.3 [7f2a623ea000 + 7e000]
```

when I get the error, eclipse crashes.

This is my operating system configuration on Debian 10 buster:
Linux 4.19.0-10-amd64 # 1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64 GNU / Linux

This is the eclipse version:
Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212

I tried to run a clear setup but I always get the same error

Could it be a software or hardware problem?

Thanks

Comment: `libglib` is a [general library of functions](https://packages.debian.org/en/buster/libglib2.0-0). By itself, it doesn't give a clue. How old is your `.metadata` folder and how many versions / updates of _Eclipse_ had it seen ? I would recommend you to close _Eclipse_, delete that `.metadata` folder and restart _Eclipse_. At the cost of having a new settings to do, this will surely increase stability.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I try to delete .metadata from workspace folder and let's see what happens, thanks

Comment: `int 3` is used in debugging. Maybe you are using some special version of libglib (e.g. with bound checks, or memory allocation checks)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't think that I have changed anything, what can I check?

Comment: Deleting the .metadata folder I got the same error after a day.

Comment: do you have other advice?